# Establish Redis Connection in Phoenix

Tags: redis, phoenix-framework

I need to establish a Redis connection when my Phoenix app initially loads. When reading the docs I thought that code would go in `/config/dev.exs` or `/config/config.exs` but the Redix dependency I am using as a Redis interface is not loaded in `/config`

Below results in a reference error in `/config`:
`Redix.start_link("redis://localhost:6379/3", name: :redix)`

I only want to call this once on app load. Where should I put this call in my Phoenix app?

Answer (score 0):

Adding `{Redix, name: :redix}` to `children` array in `application.ex` adds redix process to the supervisor tree. Which means it will start along with your application:

```
    children = [
      # Start the Ecto repository
      MyApp.Repo,
      # Start the Telemetry supervisor
      AppWeb.Telemetry,
      # Start the PubSub system

      ....

      # Single Redis connection
      {Redix, name: :redix}
    ]
```

See https://hexdocs.pm/redix/real-world-usage.html

You can check in `iex -S mix`:

```
iex(1)> Redix.command(:redix, ["PING"])
{:ok, "PONG"}
```

Now you can use all the regular `Redix` commands: https://hexdocs.pm/redix/readme.html#usage